# How to do a partial match in Wordpress tax_query for custom taxonomy

Tags: wordpress

We search in taxonomies for certain terms. The search phrase `$search_data` (in our example: 4000342) comes from a search form field.

The query looks like this and does work in general already, when the search phrase matches the terms exactly:

```
$search_data = 4000342;
$args =  array (
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array(
          array(
              'taxonomy' => 'pa_version',
              'field' => 'slug',
              'terms' => $search_data
          )
      ),
 );
```

This search show all products with the Taxonomy term 4000342.

But there are a lot of different terms that contain the search phrase (4000342) as part of the term, for example: XC-KK-4000342-8.

We want to show all products where the taxonomy term contains the search phrase.

We tried different operators in the tax_query, but none of them seem to work in this case. How do we do a partial match using `tax_query`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WP_Query doesn't allow for a `LIKE` comparison for taxonomy searches so you will need to do 2 steps:

1. First to get a list of all the slugs that are a partial match to your search term.
2. Then use this list in your `tax_query`to search for all slugs that are an exact match to the slugs in this list.

**1. Get all slugs that are a partial match**

Use `get_terms` to get a list of all terms that include your search term `$search_data`.

You don't need regex - `get_terms` already has an argument `name__like` that will perform a partial match instead of a full match.

```
$matching_terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'pa_version',
    'fields' => 'slugs', // searches in the slug and returns an array of matching slugs
    'name__like' => $search_data, 
) );
```

This will return an array of all the slugs that partially match your search term, e.g. `('4000342', 'XC-KK-4000342-8', '123440003425')`.

(**Note:** `get_terms` doesn't returns terms that are empty by default. If you want to include empty terms, you can include `'hide_empty' => false` in the arguments.)

**2. Use this in your `tax_query` to search all slugs that are in this list**

```
$args =  array (
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array(
          array(
              'taxonomy' => 'pa_version',
              'field' => 'slug',
              'terms' => $matching_terms
          )
      ),
 );
```

See more about this and other [WP__Term_Query parameters here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/#parameters) that can be passed to `get_terms`

Comment: I understand the logic behind. But $matching_terms does not output anything. Not even if the complete term slug is the exact search_data, e.g.  4001681.
The part "'name__like' => 4001681" does not work for some reason.

Comment: This code works because I have used it before in a website, so there is something else affecting it. Do you have any other args in your query? Also, what version of Wordpress are you using? The functionality of get_terms changed between versions. If you var_dump($matching_terms); what do you get?

Comment: "var_dump($matching_terms);   =>    array(0) { }   " The args look correct. Nothing else in there. Seems like the search string is not correct. But when I echo the search string its shows the exact stzring, like the term slug and name (booth are the same). I use WP 5.4.2.

Comment: WP version is fine. Hmmm... If you leave out the name__like arg, is your slug included in the var_dump results? Also, I wonder if the problem is because it’s a number and it’s treating it differently... Try changing your search string to one of the non-numerical slugs that shows in the previous var_dump.

Comment: Hey, thanks alot. It does work and I found the problem.
Some Attribute terms are not correct assigned to the products. They are visible inside the product (backend & Frontend), but when I visit "Products=> Attributes" the attribute terms show the count 0 (amount of products attached to the certain taxonomy term). 
Do you have clue how to fix that?

Comment: Glad it worked for you! It sounds like you are using some WooCommerce or some other e-commerce plugin? I’m not familiar with that so I’m afraid I can’t help. Try asking on Wordpress.stackexchange.com - Stackoverflow is for coding questions and this sounds more general so you’re more likely to get help over there (questions with no code will just get downvoted here). Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a regex. First you need to get all the terms:

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'pa_version',
    'fields' => 'slugs',
) );
```

Then get the regex result:

```
$filtered_terms = preg_grep('/' . $search_data . '/gm', $terms);
```

And use it in your tax query:

```
$args =  array (
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pa_version',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $filtered_terms
        )
    ),
);
```

P.S. There in no query parameter called `field` in get_terms which is documented in `WP_Term_Query::__construct`.

Comment: Thanks so far. But I cant get it to work. If I echo $filtered_terms its empty. What does the '/gm' part mean? And $terms is an array, right?. Does preg_grep search through the array by itself?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, the terms query should use "field" property and not "fields", I change the answer, try it this way and tell me if it works

Answer (score 0):

You need to use relation 'OR' for showing products from both taxonomies or relation 'AND' for showing products with both taxonomies, something like this:

```
$args =  array (
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array(
          'relation' => 'OR',
          array(
              'taxonomy' => 'pa_version',
              'field' => 'slug',
              'terms' => 4000342,
          ),
          array(
              'taxonomy' => 'pa_version',
              'field' => 'slug',
              'terms' => 'XC-KK-4000342-8',
          )
      ),
 );
```

Comment: That was only an example. The user uses a search form. So the term he searches for will come from a search form.
We have thounsands of 7 digit numbers the user will search for. And also thousands of other terms that contain the 7 digits. So we cant work like in your example.